# Frigidaire Stove Model FEF368GSA range and oven both no heat lights and clock work

Tags: oven, stove, heat

I am in a mobile home that was built in the 1970s. Someone flipped the circuit breaker to the electric  stove. Now the clock and oven lights work but no heat from any of the burners or oven. We replaced the oven control board but it did not fix the problem. I tested the 240v circuit with a multi-meter. I am getting 120v per side so we should be getting the 240v altogether. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What make and model is the breaker panel? I'm suspecting you have a bad leg or bad connection on one leg

Comment: It is a GE Load Center. Underwriters Lab Enclosed panelboard 1270 P-14. Cat. NO. Surface type/TLM812ST Mod 1. Surface Type/TLM812FT. Testing Laboratories Approved 182 Service Panel. I'm not sure if that is the information your looking for.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off, and **firmly** back on again? Is it two handles joined, or just one handle? Could be you are only getting it "half-on" and the fact that you have not measured 240 directly leads to the possibility that the 120V you are seeing from one side is actually from the other side passing through a low resistance element...

Comment: I have tried flipping the switch back and forth but it hasn't helped. It is a single not a double handle.

Comment: I will try to measure 240v all at once instead of two 120s. Thanks